# Jenkins skip some jobs in chain of freestyle jobs

Tags: jenkins

We got a requirement to implement CICD using Jenkins.
Here, Jenkins is running in windows machine and application server running in linux machine and build activity should happen in Linux system. So, We are connecting to linux machine using Jenkins's SSH plugin and executing jobs.
I have created list of freestyle jobs to checkout code from CVS, cleanup activity, Build , stop server, start server, Run Junit, run sonar. all these jobs are chained using 'build other projects' option in post build Action section.
Here, all jobs executes in sequential manner. But, sometimes I need to execute only few jobs like stop and start server.
So, please help me how we can randomly pick jobs which need to be run before triggering build.

Thanks, 
Ganesha

Comment: Is there a reason to have so many jobs ? Try adding all these tasks to jenkins pipeline and then use job parameters and conditional statements to run what you want. Or at least trigger another jobs from conditional statements.

Comment: Thank you.. I will try these methods